# Updating binary data on a smartcard on an offset higher than 32767

Tags: apdu

Can anyone help me with the layout of the data field in an Odd INS UPDATE BINARY command? Specification tells "'54' '02' {Offset data object in file} || '53' L53 {Discretionary data object}". On all my tries I get Status Word result '6700', which is "Wrong length: no further indication". Please provide an example if possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The "||" does not mean OR. So the data object of the Odd INS UPDATE BINARY shoud be "54 02 {any offset in two bytes} 53 01 FF". This update the data at the offset to FF.