# How to update a Smart card EF greater the 32KB limitations?

Tags: smartcard

I am trying to update an EF (Elementary File) that is 64K.  I know there is a limitation of 32767 for a transparent EF.

I have created an update_binary function to write to the card's EF.  However it only works  within the 32767 specification.  Has anyone done this before, update  an entire 64K EF.  If so can you please help?

Comment: @owlstead How long does it take to read the 32kb file?

Comment: @jlanza Depends on many factors, can't tell you for my implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can update the EF by using `UPDATE BINARY ODD INS` (INS = D7h) found in ISO 7816-4 if it has been implemented by the particular smart card operating system. In that case you need to supply the offset within a BER encoded data object (DO).

See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938004/updating-binary-data-on-a-smartcard-on-an-offset-higher-than-32767) for the format of the command, or look in the vendors documentation (few if any operating systems are fully implementing ISO 7816-4, and many make mistakes). Buying ISO 7816-4 would also be an option of course.

Comment: You need to use multiple UPDATE BINARY APDU's of course, and you can start with even INS UPDATE BINARY's if you want to. READ BINARY works the same way, but be carefull only to increase the offset with the bytes *actually* received. Reading exactly up to the end of the file using READ BINARY ODD INS is a more complex problem than you would think.